# Remove space charater in list

Tags: python, list

How do I go about removing the space (' ') in this list?

```
list = ['a', 'b', 'c', ' ', '1', '2', '3', ' ', 'd', 'e','f']
```

As far as I know, pop / remove method works with slices but the space character changes position depending on the input.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A conditional [comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) will do:

```
lst = ['a', 'b', 'c', ' ', '1', '2', '3', ' ', 'd', 'e','f']  # do not shadow 'list'

lst = [x for x in lst if x != ' ']
```

If you have to mutate the existing `list` object and not just rebind the variable, use slice assignment

```
lst[:] = [x for x in lst if x != ' ']
```

In case you want to remove any string that consists solely of whitespace characters, you can utilize `str.strip()`

```
lst = [x for x in lst if x.strip()]
```

Note that rebuilding the list from scratch is often better performance-wise than repeatedly calling `del`, `pop` or `remove` as each of those calls has linear complexity since all the elements after the deletion index need to be shifted in the underlying array.

Comment: Thank you. I used the str.strip() method and it works great.

Answer (score 1):

you can do by using `del` function that delete the element from the list.

**Code :**

```
lst = ['a', 'b', 'c', ' ', '1', '2', '3', ' ', 'd', 'e','f']
count = 0
for i in lst:
    if i == ' ':
        del lst[count]
    count = count + 1
print(lst)
```

**Output :**

```
['a', 'b', 'c', '1', '2', '3', 'd', 'e', 'f']
```

Answer (score 0):

Below is the functional approach to achieve what you want:

```
list_input = ['a', 'b', 'c', ' ', '1', '2', '3', ' ', 'd', 'e','f']
print(list(filter(lambda elem: elem != ' ', list_input)))

# Output: ['a', 'b', 'c', '1', '2', '3', 'd', 'e', 'f']
```

More pythonic list-comprehension approach:

```
list_input = ['a', 'b', 'c', ' ', '1', '2', '3', ' ', 'd', 'e','f']
print([elem for elem in list_input if elem != ' '])         

# Output: ['a', 'b', 'c', '1', '2', '3', 'd', 'e', 'f']
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to remember of [`itertools`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/itertools.html):

```
from itertools import filterfalse

list(filterfalse(lambda x: x == ' ', lst))
#=> ['a', 'b', 'c', '1', '2', '3', 'd', 'e', 'f']
```